# Aura component unable to find apex controller method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, aura-enabled

This problem is going on and on on my orgs.

I use VS code as my IDE and whenever I deploy a freshly written `@AuraEnabled` method in a controller, for some time my org does not seem to recognize it. I can see it that it exists in the org when I enter developer console (or Apex Classes in setup) and check if the new code is in the class, however the aura component (embedded in a VF page) does not seem to know about it.

The weird thing for me is that it can recognize any other `@AuraEnabled` method that is within the controller, hence it knows abot the controller.
Usually after some time the problem resolves, but it is a pain, because I cannot test it immediately after deployment.

Foo.cmp:

```
<aura:component description="Foo" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"
                controller="FooController">
```

FooController:

```
public without sharing class FooController{
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getPickListValues(){
        (...)
    }
}
```

Line that throws the error in FooHelper.js
`let action = component.get('c.getPickListValues');`

And the error:

```
 Unable to find action 'getPickListValues' on the controller of c:Foo
```

Comment: Can you Share the JS Code or read this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307938/aura-unable-to-find-action-on-the-controller-in-lightning-components?rq=1

Comment: Caching? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_disable_caching.htm

Comment: @Lakshay Gandhi The JS code IMHO does not really matter - it happens basically anytime I update any controller with a new AuraEnabled action. And after some time, the problem vanishes.

Comment: @Girbot Caching may be a good lead though, I've had this option checked, so maybe it will dissapear now.

Comment: Once again I've encountered this problem - and my solution was to change the name of the method in the controller. This time it was the same name as the method name in helper and maybe that was the problem (although, I do not see connections).